# Invalid verb showing in Reponse.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have a page redirection code like this `Response.Redirect(..//Home//Index.aspx);` The code gives Invalid verb 400 error. But if i change Response.Redirect to Server.Transfer the code works fine. Also the Response.Redirect code works fine if i access the page with localhost but if i access it with IP i get invalid verb 400 error. The code works fine outside of my network. The 400 code comes only in chrome and not in firefox. I know in case of Reponse.Redirect the browser will initiate a 302 GET request but why is it showing invalid verb?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If Server.Transfer works, then is there any specific reason why you're not using that?